# Select * from odk_prod._refinance_tags where (end_date like '%2017-06%' or end_date='0000-00-00') and app_no in ('APP-000-095','APP-000-115')

Tags: sql

```
Select * from 
odk_prod._refinance_tags 
where (end_date like '%2017-06%' or end_date='0000-00-00') 
and app_no in ('APP-000-095','APP-000-115')
```

Comment: what is your question?? syntax error?

Comment: `end_date='0000-00-00'` makes no sense as `0000-00-00` is an invalid date to begin with. Additionally `LIKE` is for string values, not for DATE values

Answer (score 0):

you missed a single quote

```
Select a.* from 
odk_prod._refinance_tags a
where (end_date like '%2017-06%' 
       or end_date='0000-00-00'
      ) 
      and app_no in ('APP-000-095','APP-000-115')
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the question is edited after my answer. i answered 41min ago its edited 18min ago have not you noticed

Comment: @JoakimDanielson look the question tittle "Select * from odk_prod._refinance_tags where (end_date like '%2017-06% or end_date='0000-00-00') and app_no in ('APP-000-095','APP-000-115') "..  you have to go history when you find some diffence or go for some comments

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your question is, but you can improve your query.

Do not use `like` for dates!  Instead, use date functions and date comparisons:

```
Select rt.*
from odk_prod._refinance_tags rt
where ( (rt.end_date >= '2017-06-01' AND
         rt.end_date < '2017-07-01'
        ) or
        rt.end_date = '0000-00-00'
      ) and
      rt.app_no in ('APP-000-095', 'APP-000-115');
```